# Netlogo 6.3 loading but not drawing vector data

Tags: netlogo, qgis

- Originally, I couldn't get the vector data to draw in NetLogo, but it was loading.
- When I included the load-coordinate-system -> the vector data would draw
- I am now trying to load two new datasets into another model using the exact same code (that previously worked and drew the vector data).
- But now it isn't drawing the vector data.

Questions:

- Why isn't it drawing the vector dataset (when previously it did)
- How can I correct this code so the vector dataset is drawn?

My code:

```
extensions [ gis ]


globals [  elevation-dataset  sites-dataset  ]

patches-own [ patch-elevation   patch-site  counter ]

;sites-own [ Name ]




to setup 
  
  clear-all
  reset-ticks 
  
  
  gis:load-coordinate-system "C:/Users/Amy/Documents/PhD/QGIS/QGIS Maps- 2.5.23 onwards/Zone2.prj" 
  
  
  
  set elevation-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/Users/Amy/Documents/PhD/QGIS/QGIS Maps- 2.5.23 onwards/z2_small.asc" 
  gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of elevation-dataset
       gis:apply-raster elevation-dataset patch-elevation
           let mx gis:maximum-of elevation-dataset
               ask patches [
                   set patch-elevation (gis:raster-sample elevation-dataset self)
                        ifelse patch-elevation > 0 
                            [set pcolor scale-color green patch-elevation 0 mx]
                            [set pcolor blue]
                           ]
  
  
  
set sites-dataset gis:load-dataset "C:/Users/Amy/Documents/PhD/QGIS/QGIS Maps- 2.5.23 onwards/zone2_sites_clipped_QGIS.shp" 
     ask patches [
          if gis:intersects? sites-dataset self [
              set patch-site true 
                  set pcolor red ]
                 ] 
                 
 end
```